# Facing the wrong direction during Amidah

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei, kotel-western-wall

What should I do if I accidentally faced the wrong direction during the Amidah? Should I repeat it? How important is facing the Kotel in the Amidah according to Halacha?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim [סימן צד - צריך לכון נגד ארץ ישראל, ודין הרוכב או יושב בספינה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_6.html#HtmpReportNum0005_L2)

If you're facing the wrong way, then turn your head towards the correct direction.

> **ב** אִם מִתְפַּלֵּל לְרוּחַ מִשְּׁאָר  רוּחוֹת, יְצַדֵּד פָּנָיו לְצַד אֶרֶץ יִשְׂרָאֵל אִם הוּא בְּחוּץ לָאָרֶץ; וְלִירוּשָׁלַיִם, אִם הוּא בְּאֶרֶץ יִשְׂרָאֵל; וְלַמִּקְדָּשׁ, אִם הוּא בִּירוּשָׁלַיִם‏

Nobody mentions having to repeat the Amida if you faced the wrong direction. It's not a prerequisite, and if you have no idea which way to face you still pray in any direction you want, and *direct your prayers* to Hashem in heaven, as it says in Shulchan Aruch (ibid) in the next line:

> **ג** מִי שֶׁאֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לְכַוֵּן הָרוּחוֹת, יְכַוֵּן לִבּוֹ לְאָבִיו שֶׁבַּשָּׁמַיִם.‏

Note that we don't really *face the Kotel*, as we saw in **'ב**  above:

- Outside Israel you face Eretz Yisrael
- In Israel you face Jerusalem
- In Jerusalem you face the [place of the] Mikdash

Comment: When you are at the kotel, I know that people face the kotel. But considering that there is currently no *mikdash*, what are they facing, in actuality?