# Changing facing during Amida

Tags: tefilla, shemoneh-esrei

Is it allowed to change facing during the *Amida*, if one has find out that he\she is facing the wrong direction?

Comment: Very similar to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67780/facing-the-wrong-direction-during-amidah), but I ask during *Amida*, not afterwards.

Comment: Maybe [related](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52685/changing-location-mid-way-during-shemoneh-esrei?rq=1)

Comment: For what it's worth, Mishneh Torah, Tefilah and Birkat Kohanim 5:1, says (in [translation](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/920167/jewish/Tefilah-and-Birkat-Kohanim-Chapter-Five.htm#v1)): "_A person who prays must be careful to tend to [the following] eight matters. [However,] if he is pressured, confronted by circumstances beyond his control, or transgresses and does not attend to one them, **they are not of absolute necessity**. They are: 1) standing; 2) **facing the Temple**;_ ...".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The Mishnah Brurah 94 s.k. 10](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.94.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes that one should not move his feet, but should just turn his head if possible. If it's too far to turn (for instance he's facing the opposite direction), one should just turn in his mind to the place of the Kodesh Hakedashim. However if he's in a shul where everyone is facing the correct direction except for him, then he should move his feet so that he will be positioned correctly like the rest of the congregation.

> ואם עמד לצפון או לדרום והזכירו לו אסור לעקור רגליו להפוך למזרח אלא יעקם פניו למזרח ודי בזה אפי' אם מתפלל עם אחרים שפניהם למזרח ואם א"א או שעומד פניו למערב יכוין לבו לק"ק ולא יעקור רגליו אך אם מתפלל בבה"כ דאוושא מילתא מצדד בפמ"ג לומר דיהפוך א"ע לצד הקהל וכן פסק בספר שולחן שלמה